# Eigenvectors of dressed states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics, rabi-model

Given the following hamiltonian: (basis $|1 \rangle ; |2 \rangle) $

$$H = \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta      & - \Omega \\
    - \Omega     &  \Delta\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the eigenvalues: $\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\Delta \pm \Omega\right)$. Now I'm asked to find the eigenvectors corresponding to the dressed states and rewrite them as:

$|+ \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) \\
    - \sin(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$ and $|- \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\theta) \\
    \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues that've found are:

$|u_{1} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{\Delta + \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2} \left(|1 \rangle + |2 \rangle \right)$

$|u_{2} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{\Delta - \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2} \left(|1 \rangle - |2 \rangle \right)$

Thus, I cannot make any identification between my expressions and exercise. What am I missing?

P.S.

According to the book, we should have:

$\sin(\theta) = \left[\frac{\Delta - \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2}$ and

$\cos(\theta) = \left[\frac{\Delta + \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2}$

Comment: It's extremely likely that you've copied the hamiltonian incorrectly. You're almost certainly missing a minus sign on the diagonal, probably on the lower-right element. Otherwise the diagonalization is trivial, by just removing the constant diagonal.

Comment: I copied exactly as it is in the sheet.  Let's say that the hamiltonian had a minus sign in the diagonal, how could I get the dressed state?

Comment: Even without the minus sign on the diagonal, you still have the wrong eigenvectors. The solution is "trivial" in the sense that the eigenvectors are fairly simple and there is no need to describe them in terms of $\theta$. I think this is why the other commenter thinks you are missing the minus sign. You still get the "dressed state" the same way.

Answer (score 1):

> $$H = \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
>     \Delta      & - \Omega \\
>     - \Omega     &  \Delta\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

> I found the eigenvalues: $\lambda_{\pm} = \Delta \pm \Omega$.

The eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are actually half of the ones listed above (times hbar):
$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\Delta \pm \Omega\right)
$$

> $|u_{1} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{\Delta + \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2} \left(|1 \rangle + |2 \rangle \right)$

> $|u_{2} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{\Delta - \Omega}{\Omega}\right]^{1/2} \left(|1 \rangle + |2 \rangle \right)$

The above eigenvectors you found are not both correct. The above eigenvectors effectively just differ in normalization factor (that is to say, they are effectively the same).

One of the eigenvectors should have a minus sign between the basis vectors (and the normalization on one is wrong).

---

If the Hamiltonian actually looks like this:
$$H = \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta      & - \Omega \\
    - \Omega     &  -\Delta\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the eigenvalues are $\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\Delta^2 + \Omega^2)}$, and you should be able to solve for the eigenvalues and it looks like you will arrive at something close to what you expect.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your remarks! Can you help me get to the dressed state?

Comment: We can't do your homework for you. I provided the dressed states in the case of $+\Delta$ on the whole diagonal. Per the other comments, your teacher may have written down the Hamiltonian wrong on the problem sheet. If $-\Delta$ is in the lower part of the diagonal I have also provided the eigenvalues in that case. I can't in good consciousness provide much more if this is your homework.

Comment: it isn't homework, I'm trying to apply what I've learn by doing some exercises. But, yeah I understand what you are saying. Thank you either way!